# GTFS network dataset not working with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, general-transit-feed-specification

I prepared a GTFS network dataset for [Sydney](https://transitfeeds.com/p/transport-for-nsw/237) following guidelines of [Add GTFS to a Network Dataset tool](https://esri.github.io/public-transit-tools/AddGTFStoaNetworkDataset.html).

I setup a [multiprocessing python](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/multiprocessing-with-arcgis-approaches-and-considerations-part-1/) script which is working perfectly fine with 64-bit Python in my local computer.

Recently I got access to a powerful VM (Windows 10 Enterprise).

I installed GTFS tool on the VM and registered TransitEvalutor.dll for 64-bit geo processing.

But the GTFS data is giving me an IOError on the VM: "C:\Users\sahab\kitchen\30mincity\GTFS.gdb\SEP18\SEP18_ND" does not exist  ---both for Python 32- and 64-bit. But it is working with Network Analyst tool.

Network Analyst Solve geoprocessing tool only is working when background geoprocessing is disabled.

Can you give a workaround to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried any of the troubleshooting steps in this guide? If so, what have the results been?  https://github.com/Esri/public-transit-tools/blob/master/add-GTFS-to-a-network-dataset/TroubleshootingGuide.md

Comment: thanks for your comment. I checked the link previously. My issue is probably unique and didn't find answer there.